# Jsoup XMLHttpRequest not working with cookies

Tags: java, xmlhttprequest, jsoup

So I wanted to program a little Android App that would look up my timetable in the schools intranet and show it to me. Everything worked fine until the school updated the intranet and now uses Ajax to fetch the actual timetable data.

I use Jsoup to get the data from the website. First I have to get the login cookies and that works fine, but the XMLHttpRequest to get the data doesnt work with those cookies. But if I just copy the cookies from my browser into the code everything works.

```
Connection.Response loginRes = Jsoup.connect([intranet url])
            .data([My login data])
            .execute();

Map<String, String> cookies = loginRes.cookies();


Document calendarData =    Jsoup.connect([data url])
            .cookies(cookies)
            .data("startDate", "1462744800000", "endDate", "1463090400000", "studentId[]", "4012575", "holidaysOnly", "0")
            .header("Accept", "application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01")
            .header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest")
            .header("Host", "")
            .header("Origin", "")
            .header("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8")
            .header("Referer", "")
            .header("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/50.0.2661.94 Safari/537.36")
            .method(Connection.Method.POST)
            .get();
```

If I replace .cookies(cookies) with .header("Cookies", [the cookies I copied from my browser]) it works.

I tried to request the main intranet page with the cookies i get from "loginRes" and that works, so they should be correct.

Comment: Have you checked what you get back from `loginRes.cookies()` and compared it to what's in the headers from the browser? Sometimes there is an additional field taken from a hidden input field also used that you need to parse from the login page.

Comment: @Ownaginatious Well I get pretty much the same back as I have in my browser, just the sessionid is diffrent  of course. There are some hidden fields and I already submit them so I dont think thats the problem. But anyways thanks for the help.