# JSoup Request with "X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest" Header - Not Working

Tags: jsoup

I am using jsoup to scrape a web site that requires a login.  I have had no issue scraping several different types of pages this way, passing in the cookies I obtain on login.

On one page, an ajax request must be made to return an html fragment.  I tried requesting the URL made by the ajax call using Postman, which did not work initially. Instead, it returned a 302 code with a redirect Location.  When I added the header "X-Requested-With" = "XMLHttpRequest" to the request, that fixed the issue.

I tried to recreate this programmatically with jsoup:

```
Document page = Jsoup.connect(url).cookies(loginCookies).header("X-Requested-With", "XMLHttpRequest").get();
```

However, it is not returning the html fragment but instead the redirect page contents.

I looked at the raw code in Postman and there is nothing set besides the URL, the cookies, the X-Requested-With header and the GET method.

I had seen a post where someone suggested that the XMLHttpRequest header may not work with cookies -- [Jsoup XMLHttpRequest not working with cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37173456/jsoup-xmlhttprequest-not-working-with-cookies) -- but there was no answer.

Any idea why this is not working?

Comment: Can you check which user agent the postman uses and set the jsoup user agent to be the same?

Comment: TY. It is working now, but it also is working without that. I'm not sure why it was not working before.